# how to handle middle of data failure case in ssis

Tags: ssis, ssis-2008

Hi I have one doubt in ssis
 I want load  source excel file data into sql server database table.
Source excel file have  billions of data(huge data).
whiel loading time  halfoffrecords are loaded into destination table after that its failed due some data comes incorrect format .
in this sistuvation how will handle package for loading all data into destination using ssis.

source: excel(Emp information data)
destination : Table : emp 
I tried using check point configuration for rerun at the point of failure..
but its not usefully to handled  data row level and duplicate data is loading.
and I tried another way truncate data in the destination table. 
after that I used redirect row for error handling.buts its not good implementation due to 
trunating destination table.
please tell me how  many way to  achive this task(complete load) in  ssis package level.

Comment: Use look up transformation , so that when u rerun no duplicates will be inserted in destination

Comment: without using lookup transformation any other solution .because its only initial loading no need to compare  source to destination data( if I use lookup again it will take more time due comparing data).any other solution to achieve this case in ssis

Comment: I can only think of `look up` within SSIS or it has to be handled at staging db level, Your look up will be optimized if u use right columns and with out changing cache

Comment: Data Loading concepts always suggest using Staging tables, if data is incorrect format in source file, how would that be corrected for rerun. This doesn't sounds like a feasible solution, you will end up with performance issues within SSIS although checkpoint is enabled

Comment: You can trap and redirect the errors? Or even better transform the malformed data based on rules. Some acceptable transforms usually entail trimming, null handling, or other basic fixes.

Answer (score 0):

Load your data from Excel into a staging table, which you truncate before every load.

Make all of the columns of the staging table `nvarchar(max)` type, so they can handle any format of incoming character data.

Then run a stored procedure that de-dupes, formats and transfers the data to the final destination table.